# Ruby on Rails - Not downloading file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, download

I have this link for the download

```
<%= link_to "Curriculum Vitae", "/download/#{@user.candidato.cv.url}/#{@user.candidato.cv.content_type}" %>
```

if i did the bad way without the controller method the download works. But I read many posts on the internet saying it was a bad way to do it so I tried the good way.

This is my controller:

```
    def download
       send_file params[:url] , :type => params[:type], :x_sendfile => true
    end
```

and the routes

```
match '/download/:url/:type', to: 'users#download', via: 'get'
```

And when I click the link this shows:

```
No route matches [GET] "/download/system/candidatos/cvs/000/000/001/original/blank_CV_template_Microsoft_Word.doc"
```

I've searched everywhere and I can't seem to find anything. For the files and all I'm using Paperclip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did it for me:

Controller:

```
def download
    path = params[:url]
    send_file "#{path}.#{params[:format]}" , :type => params[:type], :x_sendfile => true
  end
```

The format was added because the path even though in the console it included the extension in the controller it never did.

View:

```
<%= link_to "Curriculum Vitae", :action => :download, :url => @user.candidato.cv.path, :type => @user.candidato.cv.content_type %>
```

Routes file:

```
match '/download/:url', to: 'users#download', via: 'get'
```

Comment: You may mark your own answer as accepted after 48 hours so that other users who might refer this get the correct answer right away.

Answer (score 0):

your routes and method name is not matching. if you take a look into both "/download/:url/:type" and "/download/system/candidatos/cvs/000/000/001/original/blank_CV_template_Microsoft_Word.doc" which one it will consider as url and type. As per your match routes your link path should be something like this - "download/url/type".

Or you can also go with even simpler approach. In your link to tag just pass only the ID of CV and process it in your download method

```
match '/download/:id', to: 'users#download', via: 'get'

def download
   cv = Cv.find(params[:id])
   send_file cv.url , :type => cv.content_type, :x_sendfile => true
end
```

Comment: I've come to being able to download the file. But i needed to add .doc after the cv.url because it doesn't come with it. I tried path also and it also doesn't include the extension in the end so it can't read the file.

Comment: you can use `send_file cv.url , :type => cv.content_type, :x_sendfile => true :filename => "blank_CV_template_Microsoft_Word.doc"`

Comment: you can do some work around to add your extension to your url ex - cv.url + ".doc". But not I'm not sure of how flexible it is for your requirement.